# Hierarchical Table Graphical Creator

Tags: hierarchy

I need to buy a lot of relative simple hierarchy. And the users must me able to edit them.
I'm looking for any kind of tool who can do it in a simple way.

I need something where I can do this in a graph (organigram style)

```
    Element1
   /        \
Element2   Element3
           /       \
      Element4    Element5
```

And then convert it into a table like this

```
Element_ID    Name    Parent_ID    Parent_Name
    1       Element1     -               -
    2       Element2     1          Element1
    3       Element3     1          Element1
    4       Element4     3          Element3
    5       Element5     4          Element4
```

I don't wan't to code something, cause I think there must be some tool that could do something like this.. I think it's not something so complicated.
I've tryied with Excel, Visio and some orgranigram makers but still don't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found something...
With Visio, you can create an organigram and there is an option "Export" to Excel.
It creates something similar, but can be easily adapted.